# resampling hyperparameters in a Hierarchical Dirichlet Process

Tags: hierarchical-bayesian, hierarchical-clustering, nonparametric-bayes

The sampling scheme for the hyper-parameters of hierarchical dirichlet process (HDP) is explained in the appendix of the original paper by [Teh et al.](http://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/papers/hdp.pdf)

I agree that the auxiliary variable $s_j$ is a Bernoulli variable and has such distribution:

$$q\left(s_{j}|\alpha_{0}\right)\propto\left(\frac{n_{j..}}{\alpha_{0}}\right)^{s_{j}}$$

But in his code, he draws $s_j$ from a Bernoulli with parameter 
$\frac{n_{j..}}{\alpha_{0}+n_{j..}}$ or

$$s_{j}\sim\text{Bernoulli}\left(\frac{n_{j..}}{\alpha_{0}+n_{j..}}\right)$$

What am I missing here? It seems a bit arbitrary to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of $q(s_j | \alpha_0)$ tells us

$P(s_j = 1) = \frac{\left(\frac{n_{j..}}{\alpha_0}\right)^1}{\left(\frac{n_{j..}}{\alpha_0}\right)^1 + \left(\frac{n_{j..}}{\alpha_0}\right)^0} = \frac{\frac{n_{j..}}{\alpha_0}}{\frac{n_{j..}}{\alpha_0} + 1} = \frac{n_{j..}}{\alpha_0\left(\frac{n_{j..}}{\alpha_0} + 1\right)} = \frac{n_{j..}}{n_{j..} + \alpha_0}$

as required.